# How do I take a screenshot using GdkPixbuf?

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

Using PyGTK, I used to be able to take a screenshot using `gtk.gdk.pixbuf.get_from_drawable`.

I can't seem to figure out how to do that using PyGObject and GdkPixbuf.  I've tried `get_from_drawable` and `get_from_window` but neither work in PyGObject.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Gtk.OffscreenWindow`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOffscreenWindow.html):

```
offscreen_window = Gtk.OffscreenWindow()
offscreen_window.add(widget_that_needs_screenshotting)
pixbuf = offscreen_window.get_pixbuf()
```

Comment: Hrm, I was looking to take a screenshot of a user selected area, offscreen_window doesn't seem to let me specify an x, y, width, height.

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question - but you can always clip the pixbuf after taking the screenshot to achieve that.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't specify that. How can I take a portion of the screen to add to offscreen_window, when it takes a widget?

Comment: You can't, it only takes a widget. But you can still clip the pixbuf to the desired dimension. If you want anything else, you will have to get into Xlib.